# restricted access to document without breaking inheritance

Tags: permissions, document

I have a library about 5 levels down from the site collection top level that has three groups with access. I will probably be modifying those groups' permissions, adding more groups, etc. over the next couple of weeks, in a fast moving legal environment with many stakeholders But I need 5 external users to be able to see just one of the documents in that library. Can I send the link to just that doc, set up somehow just for them to see it - without breaking inheritance? (with a new group is fine) I can't do code, just regular site admin steps - you were a great help last week - simple does it!

Comment: Pls mention it as a SharePoint online or the version of the sharepoint

Comment: Ah yes. SharePoint 2010, and client side, not browser. Does that tell you what you need? Any insight on the first answer (already in below) for SharePoint 2010 would be most helpful. Also, I have created a group for the 5 speciality users of that document. If I add a new user to one of the big "inheriting" groups, will it populate to that same group at this lower level, after I break inheritance? Might be another question...

Answer (score 1):

No, not without breaking inheritance.

If you don't break inheritance, then you can't assign permissions to your document without also assigning permissions for whatever parent is being inherited from.

If however you're able to break inheritance, then you can just use the SharePoint 'share' option (SP2013, anyway) which will break inheritance, copy all the permissions, and add the new user with Edit permission.